# MoreViewController, edit, noneditable icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using TabBar with more than 5 icons, co I get the MoreViewController as well and can edit icons in the TabBar. But I did not find the option how to forbid editing of one of the icons - similar to More. How can i fixate one icon?

In the docu there is description of beginCustomizingItems, which if containing the item, will make it non-editable - thats what I want. But I did not find how to use this method. All is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In your UITabBarController, set your [customizableViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621184-customizableviewcontrollers?language=objc) to an array of viewControllers that can be customized.

From the docs:

> "This property controls which items in the tab bar can be rearranged by the user. When the user taps the More item on the tab bar view, a custom interface appears displaying any items that did not fit on the main tab bar. This interface also contains an Edit button that allows the user to rearrange the items. Only the items whose associated view controllers are in this array can be rearranged from this interface. If the array is empty or the value of this property is nil, the tab bar does not allow any items to be rearranged."